# Substitute for NSData deprecated dataWithContentsOfMappedFile

Tags: objective-c, ios, mmap

So [+(id)dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:(NSString *)path](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:) is apparently deprecated since iOS 5.0. It sounds to me like I should avoid using it, but then what should I use instead?

I was using mmap to create memory mapped files and it worked with iOS5, but in iOS6, something is wrong because I get an error as soon as I try to update or read the buffer.

```
  int fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
  off_t offset = 0;
  snapshotData = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
  close(fd);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `+dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:`. Pass `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` as the option. You can also use `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` instead, but I recommend the former unless it really has to be mapped. If it really must be mapped, `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` is still just a hint, so there's no promise. To get a promise, you need to write it yourself, [as discussed at CIMG](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/02/17/extending-nsdata-and-not-overriding-dealloc).

Comment: I'll try to implement as suggested at CIMG. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Reading the CIMG comments suggest that the naming of these options could be clearer. `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` will do what the deprecated API was doing. `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` will read the entire file into memory (_not usually desired if reaching out for a mapped file_).